# How to add more than 6 items in ItemList.Builder (Android- Auto)?

Tags: java, android, android-auto

I am trying to develop apps compatible to car https://developer.android.com/training/cars . I forked official GitHub samples and successfully run the app https://github.com/android/car-samples/blob/main/car_app_library/showcase/src/main/java/androidx/car/app/samples/showcase/templates/ListTemplateDemoScreen.java.
But the problem is 6 items can be displayed in a ListItemTemplate without any problem but I need to display more than 15 items. So if I add more than 6 rows I am getting exception.

I have tried:

```
ItemList.Builder listBuilder = ItemList.builder();

    listBuilder.addItem(
        Row.builder()
            .setOnClickListener(ParkedOnlyOnClickListener.create(() -> onClick("Parked action")))
            .setTitle("Parked Only Title")
            .addText("More Parked only text.")
            .build());

    for (int i = 2; i <= 15; ++i) { //if items < 6 then it works fine
      final String onClickText = "Clicked row: " + i;
      listBuilder.addItem(
          Row.builder()
              .setOnClickListener(() -> onClick(onClickText))
              .setTitle("Title " + i)
              .addText("First line of text")
              .addText("Second line of text")
              .build());
    }
```

> Exception -  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The number
> of added rows exceeded the supported max of 6

I am using `'com.google.android.libraries.car:car-app:1.0.0-beta.1'` library for development.

Answer (score 1):

**ListTemplate** : A template representing a list of items.

This template allows up to 6 Rows total in the ItemList(s). The host will ignore any items over that limit. Each Rows can add up to 2 lines of texts via Row.Builder.addText(CharSequence).

As a result, you cannot perform this action.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I have noticed that default "Phone" app is displaying more than 6 items such as contact list and recent call log. How they are doing that?

Comment: I am having the same problem. I thought it would be better after the google I/O release

Comment: I found what I was looking for. The SearchTemplate is working perfectly for me